# no se ve imagen url- Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy empezando con recyclerview y al momento de cargar a la listaRestaurant un objeto restaurant, me cargo los datos, pero no la imagen. La imagen la cargo de una url del buscador de google. La app no se cierra al ejecutar y tampoco el debug marca nada, simplemente no se ve la imagen, segui los pasos del tutorial al pie de la letra pero no consigo dar con el problema

```
//aca seteo 
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.textViewNombreRestaurante.setText(holder.mItem.getNombre());
        holder.textViewDireccionRestaurante.setText(holder.mItem.getDireccion());
        holder.ratingBarRestaurante.setRating(holder.mItem.getValoracion());
        Picasso.get().load(holder.mItem.getUrlPhoto()).into(holder.imageViewPhotoRestaurante);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

luego defino los valores para cada elemento

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurante_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (v instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

            //lita elementos (rastaurantes)
            restauranteList=new ArrayList<>();
            restauranteList.add(new Restaurante("Pizzeria Las Cuartetas","https://placeralplato.com/files/2016/01/Pizza-con-pepperoni.jpg",4.0f,"Buenos Aires, Argentina"));
            restauranteList.add(new Restaurante("Restaurant 25 de Mayo","https://placeralplato.com/files/2016/01/Pizza-con-pepperoni.jpg",3.0f,"San Miguel, Argentina"));
            restauranteList.add(new Restaurante("Panquequeria Lo de Carlitos","https://placeralplato.com/files/2016/01/Pizza-con-pepperoni.jpg",4.0f,"Villa Gesell, Argentina"));
            restauranteList.add(new Restaurante("FastFood McDonald`s","https://placeralplato.com/files/2016/01/Pizza-con-pepperoni.jpg",2.0f,"Ezeiza, Argentina"));

            //asociamos recyclerview al adaptador
            adapterRestaurantes =(new MyRestauranteRecyclerViewAdapter(restauranteList, mListener));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRestaurantes);
        }
        return v;
    }
```

por ultimo adjunto foto al momento de debuggear[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PersonViewHolder holder, int position){
    holder.txtTitle.setText(modelResultsFilter.get(position).getTilte());
    holder.txtDetail.setText(modelResultsFilter.get(position).getDescription());
    PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(modelResultsFilter.get(position).getUrl_img()).into(holder.img_profile);
}
```

Con el llamado al método **PicassoTrustAll.getInstance**.

Answer (score 0):

Si en tu adapter envias una lista de objetos `Restaurante` que es `restauranteList` :

```
adapterRestaurantes =(new MyRestauranteRecyclerViewAdapter(restauranteList, mListener));
```

En tu adapter deberías poder mostrar la imagen como lo estas realizando:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        ...
        ...
 Picasso.get().load(holder.mItem.getUrlPhoto()).into(holder.imageViewPhotoRestaurante);
     ...
     ...
    }
```

Dos causas por las cuales no cargas la imagen son:

1) El `ImageView` llamado `imageViewPhotoRestaurante` al que se hace referencia no existe en el mismo layout.

2) Me parece que tu principal problema es simplemente que no tienes definido el permiso para que tu aplicación pueda conectarse a internet, definelo dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: El permiso lo otorgue, y el image view al que hace referencia esta creado junto con las otras variables que si cargan correctamete